# Writing to xml file but not with all results

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

Could somebody please check my code and see what I've done wrong I'm trying to add an entry to an XML file. It is nearly working, when I add the entries name age and email they are being populated except when i check the file instead of saying bill bill@zzz.com 28 it just displays bill bill bill. As far as i can see everything looks OK and closed off properly but I'd like to get somebody else's opinion.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;


public partial class compnew : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/comp.xml"));
        var comp = from itm in doc.Descendants("people") select itm;
        StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/comp.xml"));
        stream.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
        stream.WriteLine("<comp>");

        stream.WriteLine("<people>");
        stream.WriteLine("<name>" + txtName.Text + "</name>");
        stream.WriteLine("<email>" + txtName.Text + "</email>");
        stream.WriteLine("<age>" + txtName.Text + "</age>");
        stream.WriteLine("</people>");

        foreach (var item in comp){
            stream.WriteLine("<people>");
            stream.WriteLine("<name>" + item.Descendants("name").First().Value.ToString() + "</name>");
            stream.WriteLine("<email>" + item.Descendants("email").First().Value.ToString() + "</email>");
            stream.WriteLine("<age>" + item.Descendants("age").First().Value.ToString() + "</age>");
            stream.WriteLine("</people>");
        }

        stream.WriteLine("</comp>");
        stream.Close();

        txtName.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
        txtAge.Text = "";
        DataList1.DataBind();
        Response.Write("Thank you");
    }
}
```

Comment: I stopped reading your question when you asked to check your code, thats what debuggers are for.. On another note, use `XmlWriter` instead of streamwriter - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx - EDIT 2: looks like i just couldnt read your code correctly also(sorry for this)

Comment: How would your xml be if I typed `>` to `txtName` (BTW you use the same textbox for name,email and age :) )

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Blow XmlWriter - just build the XML as a DOM (e.g. with LINQ to XML) and then just save it out.

Comment: `stream.WriteLine("<name>" + txtName.Text + "</name>");
        stream.WriteLine("<email>" + txtName.Text + "</email>");
        stream.WriteLine("<age>" + txtName.Text + "</age>");
`
have a closer look... my work here is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code:

```
stream.WriteLine("<name>" + txtName.Text + "</name>");
stream.WriteLine("<email>" + txtName.Text + "</email>");
stream.WriteLine("<age>" + txtName.Text + "</age>");
```

You're writing "txtName.Text" as the value to all of them, instead of txtEmail.Text or whatever your field name is.

Comment: Thanks for that. Newbie mistake

Answer (score 0):

You have `txtName.Text` being saved to `<name>`, `<email>`, and `<age>`.

```
    stream.WriteLine("<name>" + txtName.Text + "</name>");
    stream.WriteLine("<email>" + txtName.Text + "</email>");
    stream.WriteLine("<age>" + txtName.Text + "</age>");
```

Maybe change to use `txtEmail` and `txtAge`.

```
    stream.WriteLine("<name>" + txtName.Text + "</name>");
    stream.WriteLine("<email>" + txtEmail.Text + "</email>");
    stream.WriteLine("<age>" + txtAge.Text + "</age>");
```